# Как и с помощью чего отследить движение?

Tags: java, android

Нужно спроектировать приложение, которое на камере отлавливает движение машины. Нарисовать определенную черту, и чтобы по пересечении машиной этой черты срабатывал счетчик и записывал `- 1` раз прошел, `2` раза и так далее. Как такое реализовать? Интересуют все варианты

Comment: а камера закреплена статически? или может есть возможность на стене закрепить "метки". Тогда очень легко будет сравнить две картинки и определить, что там "что то перемещается. Дальше, по размеру разницы можно определить что это.

Comment: @Kovadim Ну помоему легче openCv

Comment: @Kovadim хотя твой метод тоже не плох ,делать скришоты и через гугкаудвижен сверять на наличие машин.но эт геморойно .Думвю лучше openCb

Comment: я думал написать об opencv, но как по мне, он -это просто инструмент.

Comment: @Kovadim ну да )хотя вот щас хочу норм туториал по нему найти а нету.нету ссылки на то как отлавить движение на видео?

Comment: этого добра куча. Гуглится по словам "opencv move detection" - http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/

Comment: @Kovadim Спасибо товарищ за помощ.Очень тебе благодарен!Добра!